# Google Cloud Messaging Message Privacy

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

How are GCM messages sent only to the correct Android application? What should I do in the declaration of the broadcast receiver and service in the Android application?

Answer (score 4):

From the GCM documentation :

> On the device, the system broadcasts the message to the specified Android application via Intent broadcast with proper permissions, so that only the targeted Android application gets the message. This wakes the Android application up. The Android application does not need to be running beforehand to receive the message.

The permission that ensures this is :

> An applicationPackage + ".permission.C2D_MESSAGE" permission to prevent other Android applications from registering and receiving the Android application's messages. The permission name must exactly match this pattern—otherwise the Android application will not receive the messages.

In addition, the declaration of the broadcast receiver ensures that only the GCM framework can send messages to it :

> A receiver for com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE, with the category set as applicationPackage. The receiver should require the com.google.android.c2dm.SEND permission, so that only the GCM Framework can send a message to it. Note that the receiving of messages is implemented as an intent.